# Multi-class image classification using CNN - to find 3 to 5 class & to display their name

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have tried the below code, but its only working on cat and dog, not working for the 3rd, 4th,etc class. I have downloaded data-set and stored it in *train* & *test* folders according to their name.

Please let me know the approach & plz do modify my code.

```
# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())
# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.2,
zoom_range = 0.2,
horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
steps_per_epoch = 800,
epochs = 15,
validation_data = test_set,
validation_steps = 2000)
# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras_preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('cat1.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] ==0:
    prediction = 'dog'
    #print ("Dog")
else:
   prediction = 'cat'
   #print ("Cat")

  print (prediction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

According to this, your network is making one "binary" output, which definitely won't scale to N way classification.

Depending on the exclusiveness of your label, you can either:

```
# make N binary output, and change your input label to 1 hot label (eg. 0 0 1 0 0 ...)
classifier.add(Dense(units = N, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# make N probabilistic output which sum to 1, and change your input label to class_index (eg. 2)
classifier.add(Dense(units = N, activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

either way I assume you have to dig a little deeper into your training set loader (train_datagen.flow_from_director) to make it work.

Comment: And class_mode='categorical' ? and what in case if the image is not there in train/test folder?(eg: if i have trained cat/dog/rabbit then what if I give 'Monkey'? Can I get the result 'Not found' ?)

Comment: class_mode='categorical' is probably the indexed label I mentioned as the 2nd "solution".
And no, given an unknown  input still return a trained category output as the "best educated guess"

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then two classes you have to change your loss function like this,

```
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

**binary_crossentropy** will work if you have one or two classes i.e., cat or dog, is_mango or not mango like that

hope this will help you

Comment: Also, the function before it needs to be softmax not sigmoid unless someone uses n sigmoid.